# Android Holo themes with backwards compatibility

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility

I have built android app with supporting `android:minSdkVersion="7"` `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`. I use my customized theme inheriting Android default theme.

so now i want to change whole application theme to Holo theme.Can any one help me on this.

Comment: You mean you want to change this programatically at run time? What about pre-honeycomb devices? Do you want them to have the Holo.Theme as well? Then you need something like Holoeverywhere. https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Comment: Link to HoloEverywhere is now: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 10):

You can implement a "style selector" by using different style XMLs.

Just define a theme named "StyleSelector" or something like that in `/res/**values**/styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    ... Your theme definitions
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then create a `/res/**values-v11**/styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeSelector" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Now just apply your theme with "`@style/ThemeSelector`" and let Android do the magic.
On older Android versions, your theme definition will be loaded, on newer versions with Holo-Support, your theme will be derived from Holo.

Comment: Although android documentation gives the same info, I get an error in eclipse even after specifying Theme.Black in values. I searched everywhere, but looks like there is no solution for this. Also I do not want to use any 3rd party libraries like HoloEveryWhere.

Comment: Why not @android:style/Theme then?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) as parent theme.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml that it contains the theme:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"
```

For example like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo">
```

Or you can do it on a per Activity basis. Here is the relevant documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I try this method but it gives error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/Theme.Holo').

Comment: Did this happen on a pre honeycomb device? If so, did you add the Holoeverywhere library? When using Holoeverywhere you have to use "@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark"

Comment: This is not run time error.this error gives from eclipse.so i can't build project. i will try HoloEverywhere theme.thanks for your help.