# Theme.Holo in styles.xml with level < 11 causes validation error in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I try to use the [alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) / theme selector solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736746/80901) to switch to the Holo theme on new devices. The project uses Android 2.1 as project build target.

Hoewever if I put this XML in res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo" />
</resources>
```

Eclipse indicates an error:

> Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@android:style/Theme.Holo'.  styles.xml  /MyApp/res/values-v11

The manifest sets these SDK values:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I can only compile this project if I set the **Project Build Target** to Android 3.0, but then it will not run on older devices.

So this style selector workaround can not be used wit Eclipse ADT. Is this a bug in the Eclipse ADT, should the v11 styles.xml not be ignored by the ADT?

---

Update: I could use a workaround and set the file content to

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme" />
</resources>
```

to activate the default theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the App on Android 3.0< if you set `android:minSdkVersion` to a lower API.
So just set the target to API Level 11+ but set minimum SDK to 10<.

Comment: see my edit, minSdkVersion is set to 7, but Eclipse only compiles the project if I use the Android 3.0 libraries

Comment: you **can** compile with the Android 3.0 libraries, as long as you set the  minsdkversion to your prefered API

Comment: I accepted your answer (for additional hints on target device problems)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the target to 3.0 will not limit it to not run on older devices.  That would be minSDKVersion.  Setting target to 11+ just allows you to access features that are only in 11+.  You just need to be careful not to use any features in the code that use API level 11+.  One possible solution for you is to look inot HoloEverywhere which gives you Holo themes for API <11 along with ActionBar Sherlock for ActionBAr stuff that far exceeds the compatibility libraries.

Comment: see my edit, minSdkVersion is set to 7, but Eclipse only compiles the project if I use the Android 3.0 libraries

Comment: Right. So use those libraries is what I am saying.  It will still run on the older OS versions as long as you do not use any API calls from the newer API levels.

Comment: If I set the project build target to 3.0, the device selection window does not allow to run the app on a 2.1 device

Comment: Not sure what the problem is.  I have my app set to build for 4.1 and I just ran it without any problems on a 2.1 emulator.  My target is 15 and min is 7.

Comment: I am assumin the selection shows an red cross. This is not an indicator weather your App is compatibel or not. Click on the emulator. I will still run

Comment: @Ahmad yes, this was it - the red cross made me halt, it works now, thank you!